# Flutter : get url of all image in firebase storage folder

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

**Current Situation**

I have folder in firebase storage that contain number of image I want to use in my flutter app.
I would like to retrive url for all the image in the folder to use it for networkimage in backgroundimage in CircleAvatar.
To fetch the url I'm using two fuction.

```
getIconUrl(String name) async {
  final ref = storageRef.child(name);
  final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}

iconUrlFill(Map dict) async {
  Map iconResult = {};
  for (String key in dict.keys) {
    var urlResult = getIconUrl(key);
    iconResult[key] = urlResult;
  }
  return iconResult;
}
```

and trying to use it in futurebuilder.

**Problem**

Code above result in Map that key of String and value of Future, which I assume Future are url. When I use getIconUrl for futureBuilder I can reach to url by snapshot.data! but I don't know how to do that in iconUrlFill function.

**Solution I seek for**

I'm looking for solution to either question

1. how to reach to url inside Future, retrieved by getIconUrl, inside loop f iconUrlFill function?
2. is there way to gain all url of image in firebase storage folder?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to get the result from `getIconUrl` which is future data you'll need to await on that function

So here's how your code might need to look like

```
Future getIconUrl(String name) async {
  final ref = storageRef.child(name);
  final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}

iconUrlFill(Map dict) async {
  Map iconResult = {};
  for (String key in dict.keys) {
    var urlResult = await getIconUrl(key);
    iconResult[key] = urlResult;
  }
  return iconResult;
}
```

hope it helped.
And obviously, please let me know if i misunderstood any part.